# Take Android Screenshot programmatically-whatever on screen-app may be in background-not rooted device

Tags: android, screenshot, android-fullscreen

I want to take Screenshot of Android device programmatically. I have searched lot of things but wherever i found, it is saying that either your device should be rooted or only you can take screenshot of your app only, i.e. if your app is in background then it will not take screenshot of home screen.

In short, i want screenshot which gives me whatever is on screen that user can seen. My own app may be in background.

1. Device is not rooted
2. Whole screen(only visible portion to user)
3. App may be in background(but still should take screenshot of whatever visible to user, i.e. may be home screen)

Comment: Is this app spying your users? I believe you should first check whether the task is ethical.

Answer (score 0):

To get screenshot you need to get root layout of the view

```
getWindow().getDecorView();
```

Cache the View into Bitmap

```
public static File getScreenShot(Context context,View parentLayout) 
    {
        parentLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap cachedBitmap= parentLayout.getDrawingCache();
        Bitmap finalBitmap = cachedBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);
            return saveBitmap(context,finalBitmap);
    }
```

Save the bitmap on the device or such

```
private static File saveBitmap(Context context,Bitmap bitmap) 
    {
        File snapShot=null;
        try 
        {
            String cacheDirectory=getCacheDirectory(context);               
            snapShot=new File(cacheDirectory, "Screenshot.png");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(snapShot);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return snapShot;
    }
```

Comment: Sir, i think you can't take screenshot while your app is in background. And m getting NullPointer exception in above code while my is running in background.

Comment: do you have some progress dialog or alert dialog in foreground, when you are trying to take screenshot???

Comment: I tried with with transperant activity so that i can capture the background but its only showing black screen. Can you please suggest me next.

If i put the button or progress dialog then it is capturing only that portion.

Comment: yes, the above code will work for the view or layout from which it called, try calling same from activity for which you want the screenshot

Comment: Guys, can someone guide me  with getting a screenshot outside the app for non rooted device?